# Python Flask "Invalid Credentials"

Tags: python, flask, backend

I am new to Flask learning it from a tutorial video. I am trying to authenticate and get a access token. I have created user class which is in **user.py** :

```
    class User:
    def __init__(self, _id, username, password):
        self.id = _id,
        self.username = username,
        self.password = password
```

in my **security.py** :

```
from werkzeug.security import safe_str_cmp
from user import User

users = [
    User(1, 'user1', 'abcxyz'),
]

username_table = {u.username: u for u in users}
userid_table = {u.id: u for u in users}

def authenticate(username, password):
    user = username_table.get(username, None)
    print(username) # user1
    print(password) # abcxyz
    print(username_table) #{('user1',): <user.User object at 0x000001AD37543358>}
    print(user) # None
    if user and safe_str_cmp(user.password.encode('utf-8'), password.encode('utf-8')):
        return user

def identity(payload):
    user_id = payload['identity']
    return userid_table.get(user_id, None)
```

As you can see I was trying to debug with printing out everything. Inside authentication function I got username and password successfully from the request. But In result the **user** variable is None. Looks like **.get** method is not working and that is causing the error but I can not figure out why am I getting **None** there. I have showed the outputs in front of **print** functions

Comment: Can you add the `User` class? It looks like `username` is a tuple: `{('user1',): ...}`, when you're expecting just a str like `{'user1': ...}`

Comment: I have Added at the top. Yes the problem was **,** in front of self.id= _id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a typo in your program. Please remove the `,` after the username in `__init__` of the `User` class. That is syntactically correct and way of creating a tuple with a single element which is not what you need.

```py
>>> tuple_with_single_element = "python",
>>> tuple_with_single_element
... ('python',)
>>> python_string = "python"
>>> python_string
... 'python'
```